# What is a better way to iterate over dataclass keys and values?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have two dataclasses, `Route` and `Factors`. `Route` contains a value and three copies of `Factors`.

`Route` does not know how many variables `Factors` contains. I want to get the name of these variables, and then get the respective value of each one, for each copy of `Factors`.

Here is what I currently have:

```
@dataclass
class Factors:
    do: bool  # does it do the route
    hub: int # how many of the locations are hubs

    def __init__(self, do_init):
        self.do = do_init
        self.hub = 0 # will add later 

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.do


@dataclass
class Route:
    route: tuple
    skyteam: Factors
    star: Factors
    oneworld: Factors

    def __init__(self, route):
        self.route = route.get('route')
        # this could probably be done with one line loop and a variable with names
        self.skyteam = Factors(route.get('skyteam'))
        self.star = Factors(route.get('star'))
        self.oneworld = Factors(route.get('oneworld'))

    def __str__(self):
        table = [[self.route, "SkyTeam", "StarAlliance", "OneWorld"]] # var name is fine
        for var in Factors.__dict__.get('__annotations__').keys():  # for each factor
            factor = [var]
            factor.append(self.skyteam.__dict__.get(var))
            factor.append(self.star.__dict__.get(var))
            factor.append(self.oneworld.__dict__.get(var))
            table.append(factor)
        return tabulate.tabulate(table, tablefmt='plain')
```

Input is

```
{'route': ('BOS', 'DXB'), 'skyteam': True, 'star': True, 'oneworld': True}
```

Current output is

```
('BOS', 'DXB')  SkyTeam  StarAlliance  OneWorld
do              True     True          True
hub             0        0             0
```

Maybe I could search `Route` for each variable that contains a `Factors` datatype and iterate over those?

Comment: I got here because I also want `tabulate` to support data classes as rows.

Answer (score 68):

You may use [dataclass.fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

for field in fields(YourDataclass):
    print(field.name, getattr(YourDataclass, field.name))
```

Comment: I'm always surprised that we have to use `getattr` and that they didn't plan access via a simple attribute like `field.value`.

Answer (score 15):

Probably the simplest way is to import `asdict` from `dataclasses`, and then write something like:

```
for key, value in asdict(route).items():
    ...
```

For a small dataclass, the cost of copying the dataclass object to a new dictionary is outweighed by the convenience and readability.

Answer (score 8):

I'd also make use of the `__dataclass_fields__` which returns a dict of the variable names and their types. For example something like:

```py
for field in mydataclass.__dataclass_fields__:
    value = getattr(mydataclass, field)
    print(field, value)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't appear to be documented. It's the same attribute returned by `dataclasses.fields()`, though. Probably better to use the latter.

Answer (score 6):

I'd leave the builtin `__str__`s alone and just call the function `visualize` or something on the `Route` class, but that's taste. You also shouldn't overload the `__init__` of a dataclass unless you absolutely have to, just splat your input dict into the default constructor.

Final nit, try to use `getattr`/`setattr` over accessing the `__dict__`, dataclasses are popular for using `__slots__` to store their attributes, which would break your code in a non-trivial way.

So I'd go with something like this, using the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library to handle the rendering:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
import tabulate

@dataclass
class Factor:
    do: bool
    hub: int = 0 # this is how to add a default value


@dataclass
class Route:
    route: tuple
    skyteam: Factor
    star: Factor
    oneworld: Factor

    def __post_init__(self):
        # turn Factor parameter dicts into Factor objects
        for field in fields(self):
            if issubclass(field.type, Factor):
                setattr(self, field.name, field.type(getattr(self, field.name)))

    def visualize(self):
        factors = {
            field.name: getattr(self, field.name)
            for field in fields(self)
            if issubclass(field.type, Factor)
        }
        rows = [[self.route, *factors]]  # header
        for field in fields(Factor):
            rows.append([field.name, *[getattr(f, field.name) for f in factors.values()]])
        print(tabulate.tabulate(rows))
```

Which works out fine for your example:

```py
>>> r = Route(**{'route': ('BOS', 'DXB'), 'skyteam': True, 'star': True, 'oneworld': True})
>>> r.visualize()
--------------  -------  ----  --------
('BOS', 'DXB')  skyteam  star  oneworld
do              True     True  True
hub             0        0     0
--------------  -------  ----  --------
```

---

This solution should continue to work both if you add more fields to the Factor class and more factor instances to the Route.

Comment: could `*[f for f in factors]` be `*factors`?

Comment: @wuyudi absolutely can, that line was an artifact from an earlier version. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To access the fields within the class itself, here is what I tried.

```
from dataclass import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class someDataclass:
    def access_fields(self):
        for field in fields(self.__class__):
            print(field) # you get the Field() instances
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the key-value pairs, you can add this method to your dataclass:

```
def items(self):
    for field in dataclasses.fields(self):
        yield field.name, getattr(self, field.name)
```

Then loop as usual:

```
for key, value in obj.items():
    do_stuff(key, value)
```